# What customisations could add "disabled" attribute to Read-Only users on subgrid in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In our customized CRM, we have users with read-only access.

[image: read-only user]

When they view some entities that include a subgrid, some have a surrounding `span` with the attribute `disabled=disabled`. (All have a span, some are disabled, some other are not)

[image: Customized CRM, disabled attribute on the span]

This attribute does not appears in a *vanilla* CRM.

[image: Vanilla CRM, no disabled attribute on the span]

For both case, javascript was disabled. So it's not inserted by a common script ([The only information](http://rajeevpentyala.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/disabling-sub-grid-using-jscript-in-crm-2011/) I found on disabled subgrid is about *adding* the disabled attribute on the span with a script. Mine is already there.)

Both CRM have the same version (5.0.9690.3911).

The example provided is the incident entity with the tasks subgrid.

I'm looking for suggestions on where this disabled attribute might come from.

This issue is important because a [disabled span in IE means a disabled scrollbar](http://jsfiddle.net/qvvv3obb/). No way for a read-only user to view all elements of a well-supplied subgrid.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it's possible to pull that off if you've made your own subgrid instead of using one of CRM's out-of-the-box ones by creating one on a webpage and putting it onto the page as a web resource.